# Can't Access the Object's Child's Mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to get the mesh from the gameObject's Children for my game's placement system.

The gameObject is an Empty Object and the Child has all of the mesh.

But the error message says

> Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.Mesh' to 'UnityEngine.MeshFilter'

How can I solve this bug? or is there any better way to get a mesh from an gameObject's children by code

```
MeshFilter viewedModelFilter = (MeshFilter)gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
buildingPreviewMesh = viewedModelFilter.mesh;
```

(buildingPreviewMesh is a private Mesh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the other answer,
First, get the Mesh Filter component.

```
MeshFilter viewedModelFilter = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>();
```

Once you get the MeshFilter, you may access the Mesh using

```
buildingPreviewMesh = viewedModelFilter.mesh;
```

OR

```
 buildingPreviewMesh = viewedModelFilter.sharedMesh;
```

You just need to do it step by step to understand it well first.. Or you can also go for the direct approach suggested in the other answer. Also note that GetComponentInChildren only returns the first child gameobject's MeshFilter component. if you have multiple children, you'll need to implement arrays to store the multiple mesh filters.

Answer (score 0):

Im not on unity right now so i cant try this right now but did you try like this ?

```
Mesh viewedModelFilter =gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
```

buildingPreviewMesh = viewedModelFilter;